# Составление запроса Tsql на отбор нахождение пользователя на рабочем месте

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть 4 таблицы ,[пример БД](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/JZcx/SSiojVWkD) (пример бэкап)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
COMPUTER (
Computer_id PK int not null, --Id Com  
Name varchar(255) not null ) --Name Com


USER (
User_id PK int not null, -- id пользователя
Login varchar(255) not null , -- login users
Name varchar(255) not null ) -- ФИО Users


S_EVENT ( 
Event_id  PK int not null,  --1,2,3,4
Name varchar(255) )-- Id События 1 Вкл ПК 2 Выкл ПК 3 Вход user 4 Выход user

EVENTS(
Num int identity PK not null , -- Номер события
Computer_id , -- Наследует из Computer
User_id ,-- Наследует из User
Event_id,--Наследует из Event
date -- Сегодняшняя дата и время(Getdate()))
```

Задача
Сформировать запрос,где будет 2 столбца

1 Это поле Name (ФИО Сотрудников)

2 Статус Компьютера ,где мы берём сравниваем

Если события за СЕГОДНЯ(завтра уже не должно работать) у данного пользователя (Event_id = 3) == (Event_id = 4),то "пользователь отошёл(обедает)"

Если события (Event_id = 3) > (Event_id = 4) у пользователя за всё время ,то " Пользователь работает"(он может работать со вчерашнего дня)

Если последнее событие (Event_id = 2) и (Event_id = 1) или User_id = null у пользователя ,то " Пользователя нет"(Значение у пользователя null в событиях 1 и 2,так как он ещё не зашёл в систему)

```
SELECT        MAX(Num) AS num,  User_Id ,Event_Id
FROM            dbo.EVENTS
WHERE        datename(DD,getdate()) =datename(DD, date)  and User_Id is not null
                                                GROUP BY User_Id ,Event_Id
                                                order by  User_Id
```

Это один из примеров моих попыток запроса.

Comment: Задачу Вы описываете слабопонятно... создайте fiddle с тест-данными и покажите желаемый результат для них.

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/oue9/2Za4jnv9v   
Где зеленый,человек на месте
Желтый отошел
Серый отсутствует

Comment: СОЗДАЙТЕ FIDDLE. А по фотографиям мы не лечим...

Comment: https://dbdesigner.page.link/qNW7P9eyYBCmekSY8     +   я в описании скидывал BackUp БД

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT [USER].[Name]
      ,CASE
           --Если на компьютере, где зафиксировано последнее событие пользователя, не происходило
           --событий включения, выключения или входа другого пользователя, то оцениваем тип
           --события
           WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                             FROM [dbo].[EVENTS]
                            WHERE [EVENTS].[Computer_Id] = [LastAction].[Computer_Id] AND
                                  [EVENTS].[Num] > [LastAction].[Num] AND
                                  [EVENTS].[Event_Id] IN (1, 2, 3))
           THEN CASE
                    --Если последним событием был вход пользователя, то считаем, что пользователь
                    --«работает»
                    WHEN [LastAction].[Event_Id] = 3
                    THEN N'работает'
                    --Если последним событием за текущий день был выход пользователя, а так же в
                    --этот день на этом же компьютере был зафиксирован его вход, то считаем, что
                    --у пользователя «перерыв»
                    WHEN [LastAction].[Date] = CAST(getdate() AS date) AND
                         [LastAction].[Event_Id] = 4 AND
                         EXISTS(SELECT *
                                  FROM [dbo].[EVENTS]
                                 WHERE [EVENTS].[Computer_Id] = [LastAction].[Computer_Id] AND
                                       [EVENTS].[User_Id] = [LastAction].[User_Id] AND
                                       CAST([EVENTS].[Date] AS date) = [LastAction].[Date] AND
                                       [EVENTS].[Event_Id] = 3)
                    THEN N'перерыв'
                    --Иначе считаем, что пользователь «отсутствует»
                    ELSE N'отсутствует'
                END
           --Иначе считаем, что пользователь «отсутствует»
           ELSE N'отсутствует'
       END AS [State]
  FROM [dbo].[USER]
       --Для каждого пользователя ищем последние связанное с ним событие в таблице событий
       OUTER APPLY (
                        SELECT TOP 1
                               [EVENTS].[Num]
                              ,[EVENTS].[Computer_Id]
                              ,[EVENTS].[User_Id]
                              ,[EVENTS].[Event_Id]
                              ,CAST([EVENTS].[Date] AS date) AS [Date]
                          FROM [dbo].[EVENTS]
                         WHERE [EVENTS].[User_Id] = [USER].[User_Id]
                         ORDER BY [EVENTS].[Num] DESC
                   ) AS [LastAction]
```

P.S. Если это для реального проекта и запрос должен выполняться часто, то лучше вообще пересмотреть структуру БД: добавить поля в таблицу пользователей и компьютеров и обновлять их в момент события. Потому что для частого выполнения запроса нужно чтобы были эффективные индексы иначе при росте числа строк в таблице с событиями будут появляться тормоза. А делать индексы по идентификаторам пользователя и компьютера в данном случае практически бесполезно, так как у них слишком маленькая селективность. Но это уже выходит за рамки вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо огромное,подскажите тогда какие требуется добавить поля в таблицу пользователей и компьютеров и почему.